# How to store jQuery function in an object for later access?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery function:

```
$('.time_tracker').each(function() {

  var hours, minutes, seconds;

  ...

});
```

Is there a way to store the result of each function call in an object, so I can access variables such as `hours` again later?

Comment: Use `.data()` to store it. Example: `$(this).data(‘hours’, hours)`.

Comment: Are you planning on accessing the variable outside of the .each() function?

Comment: @Terry Never use smart quotes in Javascript, it will cause problems

Comment: It seems like my phone tries to me smart and converted my dumb quotes to their smart counterparts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on [@Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry)'s comment, you can use the following code inside your `each()` function:

```
$(this).data({
    "hours", hours,
    "minutes", minutes,
    "seconds", seconds
});
```

This will add the variables value to the `.time_tracker`'s data attribute using key/value pairs.

> The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.
>
> The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.

In order to access the data from each individual `.time_tracker` you would need to assign each `.time_tracker` element a unique ID. You could then access those values from anywhere by using:

```
$('.time_tracker#time_tracker_1').data('hours');
$('.time_tracker#time_tracker_1').data('minutes');
$('.time_tracker#time_tracker_1').data('seconds');
```

If you wanted to save yourself the hassle of manually adding unique ID's to each `.time_tracker`, you could assign a unique ID using jQuery, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < $('.time_tracker').length(); i++) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'time_tracker_' + i);
        var hours, minutes, seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `.attr('data-seconds', seconds)` over the `.data('seconds', seconds)` method because:

> Regarding HTML5 data-* attributes: This low-level method does NOT retrieve the data-* attributes unless the more convenient .data() method has already retrieved them.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

In other words, the data is only stored in jQuery. Which is good if security is a concern and you don't want the user to have access to the data. Although it's more prone to mutability issues that are tough to troubleshoot. Attributes on the other hand are stored with the element itself in the DOM, so you can easily debug them in your web consoles inspector.

You can access the data stored by using `$(selector).attr('data-seconds')`.

You can also apply multiple attributes at once by passing an object

`.attr({'data-hours': hours, 'data-minutes': minutes, 'data-seconds': seconds})`

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

EDIT:

I guess there's a difference between `$.data()` and `$(selector).data()`

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Never the less, one of these methods should get you where you're going.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()` . It can `setting several attributes at once`. I have provide some example below so that you can access relative value later .

```js
$('.time_tracker').each(function() {
  var time = $(this).text().split(':');
  var hours = time[0];
  var minutes = time[1];
  var seconds = time[2];
  $(this).attr({
      "data-hours": hours,
      "data-minutes": minutes,
      "data-seconds": seconds
  });
  console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time_tracker">4:5:3</div>
<div class="time_tracker">4:8:3</div>
<div class="time_tracker">4:2:3</div>
<div class="time_tracker">4:15:23</div>
```

Comment: @Terry I think data() `can't set` but `get attribute` will work !

Comment: See the most voted answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50281817/395910. You can set multiple data in a single `.data()` call

Comment: I tried it with jQuery version `2.1.1` , but can't set !